# What is `c` in Jekins-Traub "A three-stage algorithm for real polynomials using quadratic iteration"

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Reading the given paper, it remain obscure to me due to this `c` variable/polynomial which is not explained.

Due to my limited knowledge of Mathematics, I did not achieved to understand further.

Given an polynomial equation of degree $n$:
$$P(z) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_iz^{n-i}, \qquad a_0=1,\ a_n\neq0$$
$$P(z) = \prod_{i=1}^j (z-\rho_i)^{m_i}$$

The polynomials $\sigma(z)$ and $K^{(\lambda)}$ are declared (I do not copy the full document as too extensive), and finally, the following formula is given, where `c` is not explained.

$$K^{(0)}(z) = \sum_{i=1}^j c_i^{(0)}P_i(z), \qquad P_i(z)\frac{P(z)}{z-\rho_i}$$

ScreenShot:

[image]

**Question**

What is this $c$ component?

**Reference:** 
First apparition: 3th page at the bottom.

http://academiccommons.columbia.edu/download/fedora_content/download/ac:166446/CONTENT/Traub__a_three_stage_algorithm_for_real_polynomials_using_quadratic_iteration.pdf

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general theory, the $c_j^{(0)}$ are random coefficients parametrizing some undetermined polynomial of degree $n-1$.

Note that $P_j$ are the eigenfunctions/-vectors of the iteration interpreted as a linear operator, so that this form of $K^{(0)}$ corresponds to an eigen-decomposition. Note that the goal is convergence to one of these eigenvectors, preferably with a minimal $|p_j|$.

In the practical implementation $K^{(0)}=P'$ is chosen since this is simple to implement and contains all eigenvectors since the coefficients are $c_j^{(0)}= m_j> 0$.